# Как узнать длину строки у двумерного динамического массива

Tags: c++

Выделаю память для строк столбцов массива так:

```
    int n=11;
    int **mas = new int *[n];
```

Потом каждому столбцу выделаю разное количество строк:

```
for (k = n - 1; k >= 0; k--)
{
   gcd=1 + rand() % 8 ;
    mas[k] = new __int64[gcd];
}
```

Как узнать длину каждой строки отдельно подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: в Си нет `new`. А размеры таких массивов надо где-то хранить, иначе — ни как...

Comment: Это c++, вроде пишу c++, он почему-то меняет на с

Comment: Даже если это скомпилировано C++ компилятором, это остается чистый C код. Ответ на Ваш вопрос - никак. Хранить размеры, или использовать `std::vector`.

Comment: @andy.37: Нет, ни в коем случае. Семантики языков С и С++  (даже при в точности совпадающем коде) настолько различны и несовместимы, что нет никакого смысла назвать С++-код С-кодом ни при каких обстоятельствах.

Comment: @AnT в данном случае, я погорячился, в С нет оператора `new`. Но это не отменяет возможности писать на плюсах С-код, и этот, если заменить new на malloc, будет именно таким.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни в С++ после выделения памяти с помощью

```
T* = new T[42];
```

ни в C после

```
T* = (T*) malloc(sizeof(T) * 42);
```

невозможно узнать размер выделенной памяти. По крайней мере, невозможно переносимым способом. То, что Вам нужно, примерно следующая структура (Внимание: **это плохой код**)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    Foo(int n)
        : nrow(n), row_length(new int[n]), data(new int*[n])
    {
        srand(time(0));
        for (int i=0; i<nrow; ++i)
        {
            row_length[i] = rand() % 8 + 1;
            data[i] = new int[row_length[i]];
            for (int j = 0; j < row_length[i]; ++j)
                data[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    int nrow;
    int* row_length;
    int** data;
    int* operator[] (int i) { return data[i]; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.nrow; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < foo.row_length[i]; ++j)
            cout << foo[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Правильно** в такой ситуации использовать `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`

Comment: а можно, будет с вектором добавлять разное количество строк?

Comment: @Александр Ну, на то он и вектор. Любое количество строк, любая длина каждой строки.